# How to get rid of white strip at the top of the screen with adjustResize

Tags: android, android-layout

While the keyboard is open a white strip appears at the top of the screen, and it persists regardless of a keyboard state change.

If I a use `adjustPan` then it works, however, I want to use `adjustResize` only.

#### Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

#### My activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" 
          tools:targetApi="lollipop">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you using weightsum ?

Comment: please put some part of code which related: toolbar or MainActivity xml

Comment: show your xml file

Comment: just remove windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds from your theme, why would you want to add that?!

Comment: changing statusbar color is not supported in pre lollipop so if somewhere in your code you are changing it remove it. it's not a good idea for now.

Comment: @Dipalishah: I used only relative layouts and views.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentTop=“true” with the layout having back arrow, textview, and right arrow. Try to set them in LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

There's a technique called [Immersive Full-Screen](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) Mode available in KitKat. I think it is now a preferred way to implement a fullscreen Activity.

This is an [example](https://developer.android.com/samples/ImmersiveMode/src/com.example.android.immersivemode/ImmersiveModeFragment.html) from the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Remove this white strip from your activity's layout file. I can't say more as far as you don't provide your layout xml.

I advice you to use [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) for layout debug.

Comment: I have already mention that >> While the keyboard is open a white strip appears at the top of the screen

Comment: @Hits it's hard to give a more precise answer to your question as far as you don't show us the layout xml file.

Comment: @Hits look for `android:paddingTop` attribute and remove it.